# Purge all files under a directory with Varnish HTTP accelerator

Tags: php, varnish, varnish-vcl

Is it possible to purge all files underneath a specific directory using Varnish? How could you go about completing this in a PHP script?

For example, if a URL includes the path `/product/a-specific-product/`, is it also possible to purge files such as `/product/a-specific-product/a-sub-page/`?

I have the following functions that are used to purge a specific URL in Varnish 3 (part of class `VarnishPurger()`:

```
public function executePurge()
{
    $purgeUrls = array_unique($this->purgeUrls);

    foreach($purgeUrls as $url)
    {
        $this->purgeUrl($url);
    }

    if (!empty($purgeUrls))
    {
        $this->purgeUrl(home_url());
    }        
}

protected function purgeUrl($url)
{
    $c = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PURGE');
    curl_exec($c);
    curl_close($c);    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom PURGE handler in Varnish to handle regexp purges using, for instance, `ban_url()`.

For instance in PHP when you want to purge add a custom HTTP header for Varnish to spot.

```
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('X-Purge-Regex-URL'));
```

Then in vcl_recv() add

```
if (req.http.X-Purge-Regex-URL) {
  if (!client.ip ~ purge) {
    error 405 "Not allowed.";
  }
  ban_url(req.url);
  error 200 "Banned URL";
}
```

Now when you issue a purge for `/product/a-specific-product/` everything matching the regexp, including `/product/a-specific-product/a-sub-page/` will be purged.

Please note that the HTTP host is disregarded, so if you are running virtual hosts and want only specific sites to be purged, you need to use `ban()` instead with `req.http.host` and `req.url` parameters. Please let me know should you need this type of a solution instead.

Also, as mentioned, the purge is a regexp purge, so purging `/product` will purge *all* URLs matching `product`.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
// $version = VERSION_OF_VARNISH;
$command = $version >= 3 ? "ban" : "purge";
exec("$command req.http.host ~ $host && req.url ~ \"$pattern\"");
```